# Input type range Не могу вырезать диапазон

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Создал ползунок пример внизу.
Необходимо вырезать значения от 200000 до 250000.
Когда скольжу ползунком, он должен после 200 000 показывать 250 000.

Другими словами валидные значения диапазона должны быть от 90000 до 200 000 и от 250 000 до 400 000.

Необходимо исключить возможность выбора слайдером диапазона от от 200 000 до 250 000.

Спасибо за ваше время.

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("SomeController", function($scope) {
  
$scope.transv_frq = 0;
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="SomeController">
      Частота передачи: {{transv_frq}} Гц  
      <div> 
        <input
           type="range"
           id="TransiveFrequency"
           ng-model="transv_frq"
           value="transv_frq"
           min="90000"
           max="400000"
           step="25">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хотя бы предложите идею. Я сам сделаю.

Comment: Чтобы предложить идею нужно понимать, что вам нужно. Вы описали ситуацию, замечательно, что именно у вас не получается? В чем состоит вопрос?

Comment: Необходимо исключить возможность выбора слайдером диапазона от
от 200 000 до 250 000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот я накидал предположительный вариант.

Но мне в нем не нравится, как перескакивает слайдер. Необходимо, чтобы перескока не было.

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("SomeController", function($scope) {

  $scope.transv_frq = 0;

  $scope.ChangeRecvFrq = function() 
  {
    if ($scope.transv_frq > 200000 && $scope.transv_frq <= 225000)
      $scope.transv_frq = 200000;
    if ($scope.transv_frq > 225000 && $scope.transv_frq < 250000)
      $scope.transv_frq = 250000;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="SomeController">
    Частота передачи: {{transv_frq}} Гц
    <div>
      <input type="range"
             style ="width: 300px"
             id="TransiveFrequency" 
             ng-model="transv_frq" 
             ng-change="ChangeRecvFrq()" 
             value="transv_frq"
             min="90000" 
             max="400000" 
             step="25">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```